# Blob is incomplete (missing block). Blob: e8fae0af3ffeea11af8c501ac515955d

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, devops

Azure Devops On Promises Server:-

Fail to upload 'c:\AZIndAgent5_work\4\a\Installer_1.1.0.191\MODUSPlanningSuite-NoMediaSetup_1.1.0.191.exe' due to 'Blob is incomplete (missing block). Blob: e8fae0af3ffeea11af8c501ac515955d, Expected Offset: 221585150, Actual Offset: 22124953

6'.

Comment: This error message appears to have nothing to do with Git: there are no occurrences of 'missing block' in the Git source code, for instance.

Comment: yeah, this seems like upload to azure blob storage failed

Comment: This error is coming when we are running multi-agent configuration in single agent it is not there- Any suggestion from your side ?

Comment: Hi @Er Abhijit Kupale, Could you please share the full sample pipeline definition and log here?